# Is this a correct usage of rvalue references?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Consider the following function:

```
vector<int> get_vector()
{
    vector<int> xs;
    // Do some stuff to fill the vector with numbers...
    return xs;
}
```

Would it make sense to write the following instead? The main goal would be to avoid copying the vector when returning it.

```
vector<int>&& get_vector()
{
    vector<int> xs;
    // Do some stuff to fill the vector with numbers...
    return std::move(xs);
}
```

Are there any semantic differences other than avoiding a copy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are differences. Consider the following case:

```
std::vector<int> v = get_vector();
```

In the first case, we can perform named return value optimization. Which means that the local variable `xs` is actually going to constructed *in place* in `v`. No move will be done here at all. This is as efficient as possible.

In the second case, `xs` *has* to be constructed locally so that it can be moved out. NRVO is impossible, so there will be a move. So that is strictly worse.

Now consider the following case:

```
auto&& v = get_vector();
```

In the first case, this is OK. `get_vector()` returns a temporary, which gets bound to the reference and extended for the lifetime of `v`.

In the second case, we just took a reference to the temporary `xs` and now have a dangling reference. This is bad.

In summary: always prefer to return your locals by-value. They're *already* rvalues from the perspective of the caller, so there is no advantage from explicitly making them rvalue references.

Answer (score 2):

There is no copy. The caller will move it if it can. Besides, in the second one, you're returning a reference to a local, which is bad.